# Why the existence of an associative OPE for a CFT$_2$ is presented as an extra axiom in this presentation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

In the book "Mathematical Introduction to Conformal Field Theory" by Schottenloher, the author introduces in Chapter 9 one axiomatic definition of what a CFT in two dimensions is. The first three axioms are the Osterwalder-Schrader axioms for a QFT in Euclidean signature. The theory is defined to be a collection of $n$-point functions obeying three properties:

1. Permutation invariance of the Green's functions;
2. Euclidean covariance of the Green's functions;
3. Reflection positivity;

Then the author introduces more three axioms that further specify the theory to be conformal. They are:

4. Covariance under dilatations;
5. Existence of a $(\Delta,J)=(2,2)$ field that can be identified with the stress tensor;
6. Existence of an associative OPE among primary fields;

I'm somewhat confused by axiom 6, because in standard Physics oriented texts on CFT (which don't have mathematical rigor as an objective), the existence of an associative OPE comes about as a consequence of the state-operator map.

Now, axioms 1-3 allow one to reconstruct the Hilbert space with an unitary action of the Euclidean group, and to define operators on that Hilbert space that have the expected covariant transformation law under conjugation by that unitary action, and whose correlators compute the $n$-point functions we started with. Combining with axiom 4 these operators are conformal covariant and transform as quasi-primaries.

Axiom 5 allows for the construction of the Virasoro generators $[L_n,\bar L_n]$ and for the definition of primary fields. It further allows for the proof of the conformal Ward identities obeyed by primary fields.

In this setting, a Physics QFT text would already claim that we have the state-operator map and that the OPE follows. In Schottenloher's text the state-operator map turns out to be an additional assumption:

> **Remark 9.11 (State Field Correspondence)**: Assume that the asymptotic states of the primary fields together with their descendants generate a dense subspace $V$ of $\mathbb{H}$. Then to each state $a\in V$ there corresponds a field $\Phi$ such that $\lim_{z\to 0}\Phi(z)\Omega=a$.

I understand his point here. If we take all primary fields and act on the vacuum at the origin, we obtain eigenstates of $L_0$ and $\bar L_0$ and then we can form descendants. Axioms 1-5 don't seem to be enough to be able to state that *all eigenstates* of $L_0$ and $\bar L_0$ arise in this way. This seems to be an extra assumption, and I'm fine with that.

But then, after that the author presents the OPE to be an extra axiom. I don't see how is this the case. As far as I understand, axioms 1-5 plus the assumption that we can form a basis of the Hilbert space from the states $\Phi(0)\Omega$ and their descendants , where $\Phi$ ranges over all primary fields, implies in the existence of an associative OPE among primary operators.

What is going on here? Why in this mathematically rigorous presentation the OPE appears as an extra axiom? The OPE does not follow from the other axioms together with the state-operator map, as claimed in Physics texts?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411708/84967

Comment: Is there a more precise statement of axiom 6? If it includes convergence of the OPE, i.e. its validity at finite distance and not just in a limit, then it probably does not follow from remark 9.11.